# What is the potenital due to a point charge at point very near to it?

Tags: charge, potential

Consider a example, we have a thin spherical shell of Q, and a point charge q is kept at the centre of shell . For determining the potenital at the centre of the shell, we use the superpostion principle,  we get $V=KQ/r$, from outer spherical shell but what should we take the contribution from point charge placed at the centre at general point r it is given by $Kq/r$ so putting the limit when r tends to zero we find that potenial is infinite at the centre, is this true?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking about this way, think about what the definition of potential is. Let us set $V=0$ at infinity. The potential at $r$ is the work done to bring a charge from $\infty$ to radius $r$.

Now, as you come closer and closer to the inner charge, the magnitude of field of that charge that you have to overcome, which varies as $(1/r^2)$ becomes extremely high near the centre and keeps increasing as you move further. So yes, the work done to take a charge there would be infinity, aka it is not possible.

Edit after a comment: If the two charges in my answer above have opposite charges then as you move closer and closer to the inner charge, the work needed to be done by you would tend to be more and more negative as you move forward due to high attraction. In that case, reaching to the centre would require highly negative work on your part. What happens when we reach the center? Well we don't ask such questions. Point particles are mathematical models and fields are not defined at the centre.

Comment: Unless of course the two charges are of opposite sign. Then it is by your reasoning impossible to _separate_ them. If two opposite charges meet do they release infinite energy? If I were the OP then that would be my next question to @LoneAcademic.